# How to make the downloaded data appear on the screen without delay?

Tags: android, android-room, android-livedata

I have a data load method that returns LiveData. This LiveData is then passed through the Repository and ViewModel and its contents are viewed in the fragment. This happens in the onCreateView method. The problem is that the data from the database is displayed on the screen after a split second and the effect of the data appearing after starting this window is created. How can you prevent such a delay?

It is necessary for the user to immediately see this data as if it was hardcoded on the screen.

```
 @Transaction
 @Query("SELECT * FROM data")
    fun getData(): LiveData<List<Data>>?
```

Comment: There is no point of having a extra delay for this . If you want to make the UX more effective you can add some animation on the screen .

Answer (score 2):

Well that is how LiveData works. It releases your UI to continue rendering whats happening (loading the new fragment) and only updates the fields once data is loaded.

To stop this, you will have to slow down the UI transition by adding animations etc, but if a users phone is slow it might not be sufficient..

Alternatively you could design a loading screen and gracefully deal with the loading delay.